# How to invoke method when foreach is rendered using Knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, binding, knockout.js, foreach

I create a list of items by means of the foreach binding using Knockout.js. When all the items of the foreach bindings are rendered, I would like to search for an item of a specific class called "focused" and scroll a window to that item.

That will happen only once on page load as I do not add or remove the items.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use property afterRender of foreach binding.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: items, afterRender: doSomething }">
    <div data-bind="text: $data">
</div>
```

Your viewModel:

```
var vm = {
   doSomethingInvoked: false,
   items: ko.observableArray(['apple', 'banan']),
   doSomething: function (elements) {
       if (!doSomethingInvoked) { // prevent invoking multiple times
           var offsetTop = $(elements).filter('.focus').offset().top;
           $('html,body').scrollTop(offsetTop);
           doSomethingInvoked = true;
       }
   }
};
```